# Routing annotation with Symfony4 doesn't match cause of DNS?

Tags: php, symfony, dns, routes

I'm trying to make the first page creating tutorial

https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

So i use the annotation in my **src/Controller/LuckyController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * @Route("/lucky/number")
    */
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return $this->render('lucky.html.twig', array(
            'number' => $number,
        ));
    }
}
```

And when i try to go in this url

*(i.e)OVHServer.fr/project/public/lucky/number*

I got a 404 Not Found Error

I guess that it's because I didn't put my DNS in the the project/public directory but I want to know if you know a way for let the Url like that and get the road in my controller.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS is not relevant. The routing takes effect after the configuration of the server.
The public directory of symfony 2 and 3 is named `web`, it's named `public` since symfony4

For example :

```
OVHServer.fr/app.php/lucky/number
OVHServer.fr/web/app.php/lucky/number
OVHServer.fr/project/public/app.php/lucky/number
```

When your server is configured to hide the `app.php` it would give you

```
OVHServer.fr/lucky/number
OVHServer.fr/web/lucky/number
OVHServer.fr/project/public/lucky/number
```